# Defining formal languages

Tags: combinatorics, formal-languages

Alphabet $A= \{a,b\}$

Define formal languages $L_i$ for conditions $B_i$. You are only allowed to use the following symbols:

$a$ $b$ $\{$ $\}$ $($  $)$  $,$ $^*$  $\cdot{}$  $\cup$

So basically brackets, comma, concatenation and the star.

a) $B_1: |w|$ is odd and $w(0) \neq w(|w|-1)$

b) $B_2: |w| = 0$

c) $B_3: w$ doesn't have $ab$

d) $B_4: w\in L_3 \rightarrow w \in L_2$

My answer:

a) $w$ must have at least 3 symbols and the number of symbols must be odd. So the possibilities in which $a$ and $b$ can show up are: $aaa, aab, aba, baa, bba, bab, abb, bbb$

$L_1= a\cdot \{aa\}^* \cup a\cdot \{ab\}^* \cup a\cdot \{ba\}^* \cup b\cdot \{aa\}^* \cup b\cdot \{ba\}^* \cup b\cdot \{ab\}^* \cup a\cdot \{bb\}^* \cup b\cdot \{bb\}^*$

b) $L_2 = \{\}$

c) $L_3 = \{b\}^* \cdot \{a\}^* \cup \{a\}^* \cup \{b\}^*$

d) $L_4= $

Shouldn't it be then that $L_4 = L_2$ ?

Comment: $L_2$ is $\{\epsilon\}$, not the empty set. Both $\{a\}^*$ and $\{b\}^*$ are subsets of $\{b\}^* \cdot \{a\}^*$ so it's not necessary to add them explicitly.

Comment: @rici we are only allowed to use certain symbols, $\epsilon$ isn't one of them

Comment: How are you supposed to write the zero-length string, then? Because a set containing just the zero-length string is quite different from the empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**d)** No, any word $w$ that isn't in $L_3$ will satisfy $w\in L_3
   \Rightarrow w \in L_2$. In fact, $L_4 =  \{\textrm{words that have
   }ab \} \cup \{\epsilon\}$, where $\epsilon$ is the empty word.

Now you get :
$$ L_4 = \Big((\{ a \} \cup\{b\})^* \cdot (ab) \cdot  (\{ a \} \cup\{b\})^*\Big) \cup \{\}$$

**a)** Either the first letter is $a$ and the last letter is $b$, or the first letter is $b$ and the last letter is $a$ :
$$ L_1 = a\Big(a \cup b \cup a(aa \cup ab \cup ba \cup bb)^* \cup b(aa \cup ab \cup ba \cup bb)^* \Big)b \\ 
\bigcup b\Big(a \cup b  \cup a(aa \cup ab \cup ba \cup bb)^*\cup b(aa \cup ab \cup ba \cup bb)^* \Big)a$$

Comment: Thanks. Are my $L_{1, 2, 3}$ correct ?

Comment: No, $L_1$ isn't correct.

Comment: Could you show me how to do it right?

Comment: @franz3 I edited the solution. Please accept the solution (green mark).

Comment: @franz3 I'm concerned by the fact that you're not allowed to use $\epsilon$. I would have written $L_4 = \Big((\{ a \} \cup\{b\})^* \cdot (ab) \cdot  (\{ a \} \cup\{b\})^*\Big) \cup \{\epsilon\}$ or $L_4 = \Big((\{ a \} \cup\{b\})^* \cdot (ab) \cdot  (\{ a \} \cup\{b\})^*\Big) \cup \{()\}$.